# How to construct the POST request for the restful API

Tags: php, api, rest, post, restful-architecture

Currently I have an API:

http://testing2.pehk.com.hk/data/PEP/kiddieworld/phase2/pep_web7/web/index.php/kiddieworldapi/appGetTeacherInfo

If you POST "userid=544", then it will success return data like the following screenshot.

[image]

However , I tried added the userid with 544 in the POST parameter or Body, it still return 500 internal server error. I am sure the API is fine , the only problem is the structure of the request.

[image]

How to construct the POST request? Please feel free to test the above API link. Thanks.

Comment: What web app are you using ? Is it home made ?

Comment: yes home made , the API link is in the question, welcome to test it

Comment: I will give it a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to specify some information in the header as your screenshot shows.

`Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.